# Formatar valores do eixo x - Google Charts

Tags: google-charts

Preciso formatar os valores do eixo x no gráfico que estou fazendo. Não encontrei nada no Google que resolvesse meu problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como podem ver na imagem, o valor está assim R$ 1000000, gostaria de deixa-lo desta forma: R$1.000.000 ou assim R$1.000.000,00

Gostaria também que o eixo Y tivesse apenas valores inteiros

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui de uma forma bem simples, basta trocar o tipo da coluna para String, o meu estava numérico... Fazendo dessa forma você consegue escrever o que quiser embaixo das colunas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara como vc fez a consulta pra pegar mês atual e o anterior, tô buscando uma consulta assim pra exibir no meu gráfico e não consigo. Vc pode me ajudar? [dúvida aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424994/exibir-gr%c3%a1fico-do-m%c3%aas-atual-e-m%c3%aas-anterior-google-charts)