# Exibir gráfico do mês atual e mês anterior google charts

Tags: php, javascript, google-charts

preciso de uma ajuda com o charts do google.
Possuo uma tabela onde armazena id, negociador e data. Faço uma consulta para descobrir quantos acordos aquela pessoa fez no mês e consigo gerar um gráfico, o problema tá em colocar o mês anterior pra fazer o comparativo.
não quero colocar em gráficos separados, quero um gráfico só que faça isso, imaginou comparar seis meses em gráficos separados?

**Segue o código que tenho:**

```
SELECT count(id) as idCont, negociador FROM acordos WHERE month(data_envio) = ".($mes)." GROUP BY negociador

$res_ma = mysql_query($sql_ma,conexao());

function drawChart2() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Negociador', 'Acordos - <?= $row_m['mes'].'/'.$row_m['ano']; ?>'],
      <?php
      while($row_ma = mysql_fetch_array($res_ma)){
        echo "['".$row_ma['negociador']."', '".$row_ma['idCont']."'],";
      }
    ?>
    ]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Desempenho da Equipe',
        subtitle: 'Demonstrativo de meses anteriores',
      },
      bars: 'horizontal' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_meses'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  }
```

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: ao invés de negativar, poderia dizer aonde posso melhorar na pergunta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só pra deixar aqui como solucionei essa situação:

De acordo com a pergunta, para exibir duas barras no gráfico, tive que fazer duas consultas, uma pegando o mês atual e a outra o mês anterior.

**mês atual** o loop dessa consulta vai ficar dentro da function

```
$sql_gr = "SELECT count(id) as idCont, id, negociador FROM contador_acordos WHERE negociador <> 'master' AND negociador <> '' AND negociador <> 'usuario' AND negociador <> 'desenvolvedor' AND negociador <> 'admin' AND month(data_envio) = "mes_atual" GROUP BY negociador ORDER BY negociador ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql_gr,conexaoCobranca());
```

**mês anterior** esse loop foi só pra colocar o count num array e exibir no gráfico e coloquei o mês atual subtraindo 1 na consulta.

```
$sql_ma = "SELECT count(id) as idCont, id, negociador FROM contador_acordos WHERE negociador <> 'master' AND negociador <> '' AND negociador <> 'usuario' AND negociador <> 'desenvolvedor' AND negociador <> 'admin' AND month(data_envio) = ".(mes_atual-1)." GROUP BY negociador ORDER BY negociador ASC";
    $res_ma = mysql_query($sql_ma,conexaoCobranca());
    while($row_ma = mysql_fetch_array($res_ma)){
        $lista1[$row_ma['negociador']] = $row_ma['idCont'];
    }
```

**script** coloquei um ternário caso o mês anterior esteja vazio.

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Assessor', 'Acordos - 11/2019', 'Acordos - 12/2019'],
          <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              echo "['".$row['negociador']."', ".($lista1[$row['negociador']] == '' ? 0 : $lista1[$row['negociador']]).", ".$row['idCont']."],";
            }
          ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Desempenho da Equipe',
            subtitle: 'Demonstrativo dos últimos 2 meses',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_atual'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
```

Essa foi minha solução.
Abraços